# Access Firebase storage images based on uids

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I have an app where I store every users profile picture in firebase storage. This is the path I use to store the profile pictures:

```
FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-15916.appspot.com").child(user.uid+"/profile_pic.jpg")
```

[image]
[image]

I also stored the images in firebase database using their url.But when I try to access the profile pictures using this code.

```
 if (post["uid"] as? String) != nil {

               let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child((uid)!+"/profile_pic.jpg")


                imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {

                        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        cell.UserImg.image = image

                        cell.UserImg.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                        cell.UserImg.clipsToBounds = true



                    }else {

                        print("Error downloading image:" )


                    }})}
```

And I change users, the picture changes to the picture of the current user, not the user that made the post. I know the issue is in how I retrieve the images but I am not sure how to retrieve the images based on uids that are not the current logged in user.

Comment: Are the UIDs of the people who made the post included in the firebase post info?

Comment: if *uid* is the id of the current user, then all you have to do is change that for *post["uid"]* assuming you have stored the poster uid as part of the post

Comment: @Russell I changed userpic to uid but it still shows the current user's image on all the post

Comment: @KaylaGalway Yes the UIDs are included in the firebase post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fairly straightforward - although you should add some checks to ensure that you don't end up with an empty string for uidPoster

```
if (post["uid"] as? String) != nil {
           let uidPoster = post["uid"] as? String
           let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child((uidPoster)!+"/profile_pic.jpg")


            imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {

                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    cell.UserImg.image = image

                    cell.UserImg.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                    cell.UserImg.clipsToBounds = true



                }else {

                    print("Error downloading image:" )


                }})}
```